# rndc: 'flushtree' failed: unknown command

Tags: bind, freebsd, rndc

I'm very new to learning and administering DNS with BIND9 under FreeBSD. I find myself in a unique situation where I'm having an error administering the `flushtree` command with `rndc`.

I'm not sure if any of the upgrade version information matters, but I would like to get this resolved.

Below is my output and version of OS and BIND.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Jail prompt]# rndc flushtree example.com
rndc: 'flushtree' failed: unknown command

example2[12]# uname -a 
FreeBSD example2.com 9.1-RELEASE-p22 FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE-p22 #0: Mon Nov  3 18:22:10 UTC 2014     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

[Jail prompt]# uname -a
FreeBSD example.com 9.1-RELEASE-p22 FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE-p22 #0: Mon Nov  3 18:22:10 UTC 2014     root@amd64-builder.daemonology.net:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

[Jail prompt] # named -v
BIND 9.8.3-P4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the [`rndc flushtree` command was introduced in BIND 9.9](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.9.0/RELEASE-NOTES-BIND-9.9.0.txt) (released in 2012). You are running an older version, which consequently does not have this command.

It appears that you are running EOL versions of both your OS and BIND, you should probably consider upgrading also for many reasons other than the lack of `rndc flushtree`.